# Filtering relationships in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, join, filter, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have the following scenario:

```
class Author(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'author'

  id    = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
  name  = Column(String)

  books = relationship('Books', backref='author')


class Book(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'book'

  id    = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
  title = Column(String)
```

What I would like to do is load all authors who have a book containing SQL in
the title. i.e.

```
authors = session.query(Author)\
                 .join(Author.books)\
                 .filter(Book.title.like('%SQL%')\
                 .all()
```

Seems simple.

What I would then like to do is iterate over the authors and display their
books. I would expect that when accessing authors[0].books, it will return ONLY
books that have 'SQL' in their title. However, I am getting ALL books assigned
to that author. The filter is applied to the list of authors but not their
books when I access the relationship.

How can I structure my query such that if I filter on a relationship (i.e.
books), when I go to access that relationship, the filtering is still applied?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please read [Routing Explicit Joins/Statements into Eagerly Loaded Collections](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#routing-explicit-joins-statements-into-eagerly-loaded-collections). Then using [`contains_eager`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) you can structure your query and get exactly what you want:

```
authors = (
        session.query(Author)
        .join(Author.books)
        .options(contains_eager(Author.books)) # tell SA that we load "all" books for Authors
        .filter(Book.title.like('%SQL%'))
    ).all()
```

*Please note that you are actually tricking sqlalchemy into thinking that it has loaded all the collection of `Author.books`, and as such your session will know `false` information about the real state of the world.*

Comment: Will it have Author with not such books?

Answer (score -2):

In short, this is not possible. (If it were, an `Author` instance would have different `books` attribute depending on how it was queried, which doesn't make sense.)

What you could do instead is query the reverse relationship:

```
books = session.query(Book) \
               .filter(Book.title.like('%SQL%')) \
               .all()
```

Then you can access `.author` on each book to collect books written by the same author together.