# How can I stop SQLAlchemy hydrating an ORM object with results outside of my original query?

Tags: python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble with SQLAlchemy and Flask presenting data correctly to my API. There is more data in the output than there is in the ORM query due to SQLAlchemy lazily loading the relationships regardless of the query result.

I have put together a query that selects a `Classification` of `Asset` objects filtered by a subquery by way of an inner join on a relationship on the `Assets`/members/children of that `Classification`.

I have checked the SQL produced by my ORM query and it is all correct and produces the desired results. When I run the code, however, and check the API output, SQLAlchemy selects the correct `Classification` objects but then presents them with all of the `Assets` and not the filtered ones from the original query I painstakingly constructed.

As mentioned, this appears to be due to the lazy loading, the different loading strategies only appear to change how the relationships are loaded and not what is loaded and turning off the lazy loading causes it not to load at all.

Is there a way I can populate the ORM objects with only the data from the query rather than letting it go off and populate all relationships regardless??

```py
# Inside Classification class
assets = db.relationship(
    'Asset',
    back_populates='classifications',
    secondary='class_object'
)

# Inside our repository package
query = (
    db.session.query(models.Classification)
)

assets_sub_query = (
    db.session.query(models.Asset)
    .join(models.Organisation, models.User.organisation)
    .join(models.Project, models.Organisation.projects)
    .join(models.Asset, models.Project.assets)
    .filter(models.User.id == user_id)
)

query = query.join(assets_sub_query.subquery(), models.Classification.assets)
```

The desired outcome is that the `Classification` is returned and displayed with only the `Assets` from the subquery which we are joining in.

SQLAlchemy is actually populating the `assets` based on the original relationship mapping so it is including everything.

There must be a way to do this, I've looked at non-primary mappers but can't see how to map assets to a query rather than a static table in this instance.

Comment: You want `contains_eager()`, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924347/filtering-relationships-in-sql-alchemy

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä but this appears to be what I need but seems to have the effect of adding an extra table in FROM statement which I think results in an unhelpful cartesian/cross join so the results are still not as expected and the query takes forever to run!

I feel like I need 2 separate queries and somehow run them separately and populate the assets of the classification from that result. I am not sure this is possible in SQLAlchemy...