# sqlalchemy filter children in query, but not parent

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query which returns a `User` object. `User`s have a number of `Post`s which they have made. When I perform a query, I want to filter the posts found in `User.post` based on a specific time. For example, to return only the posts within 1 day of a given timestamp.

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

class Post(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Post'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.uid'))
    user = relationship(User, backref=backref('post')
    time = Column(DateTime, default=func.current_timestamp())
```

Is there a way to dynamically change the way the children are loaded by the orm, and to specify that at query time? Something like (pseudocode):

```
User.query.filter_child(Post.time in timespan)
```

Importantly, I don't want to filter out parents if there are no children which match the criteria. I only want to filter the children loaded by the orm for the given Users.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924347/filtering-relationships-in-sql-alchemy. The only difference would be the use of `outerjoin` instead of `join`.

Comment: Related, but your link involves filtering the parent based on the child attributes. In the case of my question, I do not wish to filter the parent based on child attributes, only to restrict the children loaded within the parent by a given attribute.

Comment: I actually tried an `outerjoin` with a `filter` but the result was I got no User objects back when there were no Posts matching the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Loading custom filtered collections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result) is done using [`contains_eager()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager). Since the goal is to load all `User` objects even if they have no `Post` objects that match the filtering criteria, an `outerjoin()` should be used and the predicates for posts put in the `ON` clause of the join:

```
end = datetime(2019, 4, 10, 12, 0)
start = end - timedelta(days=1)

# If you want to use half closed intervals, replace `between` with
# suitable relational comparisons.
User.query.\
    outerjoin(Post, and_(Post.user_id == User.uid,
                         Post.time.between(start, end))).\
    options(contains_eager(User.post))
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me even if I use outerjoin(). Parent objects are exlcuded from the resultset if they don't have any children that match the filter criteria. This seems to be the expected behavior according to the docs.
However, I need a way to still include the parent object with an empty list of children.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result: "The above query will load only User objects which contain at least Address object that contains the substring 'aol.com' in its email field"

Comment: @PeterPetrus Do not put criteria of children in a `filter()`, or rows not matching your criteria will be excluded, and so the parents with no matching children. Put criteria restricting children in the ON clause, if you want to keep parents with no matching children.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but what's wrong with this KISS approach?

```
Post.query.filter(Post.user == <username>).filter(
    Post.time > START_OF_DAY).filter(Post.time < END_OF_DAY).all()
```

Comment: This is returning a set of `Post` objects. I want to retrieve `User` objects, but I want their embedded `Post` collections (User.post) to have a set of objects filtered by some criteria (timestamps).

Comment: Ah gotcha, now I understand. What is the practical situation for which you want this? I can imagine there could be other ways you can achieve your goal (although from a technical standpoint it's an interesting question)

Comment: Creating computationally efficient ways to retrieve information. Retrieving data and then altering its data structure can often be less efficient than directly retrieving the data structure you need in the first place